# Как собрать vue-проект в один js-файл?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

нужно проект на vue собрать в один файл (например app.js)
Для создания проекта использовал `vue-cli-3` и команду `vue create <my-project>`

но когда собрал проект через `npm run build` получи на выходе папку `/dist/` и в ней несколько папок (/js/css/img/)

Вопрос как настроить сборку в один js-файл?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте webpack(самая примитивная конфигурация):

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: './sources/app.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        publicPath: './',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },    
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        css: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!style-loader'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'vue-style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin() 
    ]
}
```

Следует использовать следующие модули(babel по желанию):

```
npm install vue --save
npm install vue-cli vue-loader vue-style-loader vue-template-compiler webpack webpack-cli css-loader style-loader --save-dev
```

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то в vue-cli-3 структура файла настроек отличается. Там создается vue.config.js .

Comment: Я же написал используйте Webpack, намного функциональней инструмент, да к тому же если вы хотите заниматься фронтендом, то рано или поздно вам придется с ним познакомится.